# How to make a new line inside a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is my code:

```
\tikzset{Dot/.style={
    circle,
    fill,
    inner sep=2pt, % adjust the size of the dot as needed
  }
}

   \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering 
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw
            (0,0) node (v0) {} 
            (v0)--++(3,-1) coordinate(v1)
            (v0) ++(3,-1) node[pos=0.2][above=0.25cm] {Linha 1}
            (v1) node [Dot] {} node[below = 0.2] {Subestação
            virtual}
            (v1)--++(3,-1) coordinate(v2)
            ;
            \draw[blue] (v1)--++(3,1) node[pos=0.8][above=0.25cm] {Linha 2};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw
            (0,0) node (v0) {} % placing the left most source
            (v0)--++(3,-1) coordinate(v1)
            (v0) ++(3,-1) node[pos=0.2][above=0.25cm] {Linha 1}
            (v1) node [Dot] {} node[below = 0.2] {Subestação virtual}
            ;
            \draw[blue] (v1) --++(3,1) node[pos=0.8][above=0.25cm] {Linha 2};
            \draw[red] (v1) --++(3,-1) node[pos=0.8][above=0.25cm] {Linha 3};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{222.}    
        \label{Conexão Central termoelétrica - Substação1}
    \end{figure}
```

And here is the output:
[image]

I tried using double \ to make a new line between Subestação and virtual but it gives me errors. Also do you guy got any idea how to make the lines dont intersect the center of the Dot and only its edges (with the same direction)?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a document class. I use `standalone` as example. You need to set a text width key for the node. I tweaked the `tikz` code, it looks more tide in this way. If `(v1)` is associated with the `node` dot instead of coordinate then the following drawings won't intersect with it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{Dot/.style={
    circle,
    fill,
    inner sep=2pt, % adjust the size of the dot as needed
}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (v0) 
-- ++(3,-1) 
node  [pos=0.2,above=0.25cm]  {Linha 1} 
node (v1) [Dot] {} 
node [text width=1.7cm,below = 0.2cm] {Subestação virtual}
-- ++(3,-1) coordinate (v2) ;
\draw [blue] (v1) -- ++ (3,1) node[blue,pos=0.8,above=0.25cm]{Linha 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=6.1cm]
\draw (0,0) coordinate (v0) 
-- ++(3,-1) 
node  [pos=0.2,above=0.25cm]  {Linha 1} 
node (v1) [Dot] {} 
node [text width=1.7cm,below = 0.2cm] {Subestação virtual}
++(3,-1) coordinate (v2) ;
\draw [blue] (v1) -- ++ (3,1) node[blue,pos=0.8,above=0.25cm]{Linha 2};
\draw [red] (v1) --  (v2) node[red,pos=0.8,above=0.25cm]{Linha 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To use the line break `\\` it is necessary to specify the alignment with the `align` option which can take the values `left`, `right`, `center`, `flush left`, `flush right`, `flush center`, `justify` and `none`. Here are two examples and their results with your code.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}


\begin{document}

\tikzset{Dot/.style={
    circle,
    fill,
    inner sep=2pt, % adjust the size of the dot as needed
  }
}


            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw
            (0,0) node (v0) {} % placing the left most source
            (v0)--++(3,-1) coordinate(v1)
            (v0) ++(3,-1) node[pos=0.2][above=0.25cm] {Linha 1}
            (v1) node [Dot] {} node[below = 0.2,align=left] {Subestação\\ virtual}
            ;
            \draw[blue] (v1) --++(3,1) node[pos=0.8][above=0.25cm] {Linha 2};
            \draw[red] (v1) --++(3,-1) node[pos=0.8][above=0.25cm] {Linha 3};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            
        

            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw
            (0,0) node (v0) {} % placing the left most source
            (v0)--++(3,-1) coordinate(v1)
            (v0) ++(3,-1) node[pos=0.2][above=0.25cm] {Linha 1}
            (v1) node [Dot] {} node[below = 0.2,align=center] {Subestação\\ virtual}
            ;
            \draw[blue] (v1) --++(3,1) node[pos=0.8][above=0.25cm] {Linha 2};
            \draw[red] (v1) --++(3,-1) node[pos=0.8][above=0.25cm] {Linha 3};
            \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]